# Finding the simplest rational in a closed interval

Tags: rational-numbers

Given a closed interval [a,b], how would you find the "simplest rational", p/q, contained in that interval. By simplest, I mean the rational with the smallest denominator q. You may, if you wish assume that the interval is very small. We can already construct a rational contained in the interval, but in general our constructed rational does not have the smallest q. Thank You.

Comment: How do we specify the endpoints?  Are they rational numbers?  If so, then an algorithm could probably be constructed to do what you want.  If not, then it's murkier.

Comment: the following chapter on rational approximation might be useful http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-48-prev.pdf

Comment: OK. Lets suppose that the endpoints are rational and that the interval is contained in [0,1]. Further suppose the interval width is N/M, then I think you could brute force search all p/q with q<=M. That algorithm is O(M^2). Is that the best that can be done? Suppose instead that you have a very small interval and that you have continued fraction representations for both end-points. I would think that this would greatly reduce the number rationals that the algorithm would have to look at. But I still don't quite see the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Mirko. I saw the chapter on rational approximations about an hour ago. It certainly looks relevant to the problem.

Comment: If you're still here, Scot, maybe you'd like to "accept" one of the answers you've been given by clicking in the little check mark next to it.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can solve it with a Farey fraction algorithm.

Let's assume we start with $0\lt a\lt b\lt 1$.  Any time you have

$${p\over q}\lt a\lt b\lt {r\over s}$$

with $p/q$ and $r/s$ in reduced form, you can check if

$$a\le{p+r\over q+s}\le b$$

If so, you're done.  If not, replace the appropriate upper or lower bound and continue.  By starting with $p/q=0/1$ and $r/s=1/1$, the Farey fraction procedure generates all rational numbers; by zeroing in on the interval $(a,b)$, the algorithm will first produce the fraction with minimal denominator.

Answer (score 4):

We may assume $0 < a < b$. (If $a \le 0 \le b$, then $0/1$ is the solution; and if $a < b < 0$, then solve for $[-b,-a]$.)

Let the [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of $a$ and $b$ be $[a_0;a_1,a_2,...]$ and $[b_0;b_1,b_2,...]$. Let $n$ be the first position in which they differ: that is, $a_i = b_i$ for $i < n$, and $a_n \ne b_n$.

Let $c = \min(a_n,b_n)$. Then the simplest rational in $[a,b]$ is $[a_0;a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1},c]$ if this number is in $[a,b]$; otherwise it is $[a_0;a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1},c+1]$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ and $q$ are integers such that $a \leq \frac pq \leq b,$
then $qa \leq p \leq qb.$
In fact, since $p$ is an integer,
$\lceil qa \rceil \leq p \leq \lfloor qb \rfloor.$

For any integer $q,$ then, if $\lceil qa \rceil > \lfloor qb \rfloor$
then it is impossible to write $\lceil qa \rceil \leq p \leq \lfloor qb \rfloor$
for any integer $p$ and therefore there is no rational number with denominator $q$
in the interval $[a,b].$

On the other hand, suppose we find an integer $q$ such that
$\lceil qa \rceil \leq \lfloor qb \rfloor.$
We can set $p = \lceil qa \rceil,$ and we then have $a \leq \frac pq \leq b.$

This suggests a brute-force algorithm: set $q$ initially to $1.$
If $\lceil qa \rceil > \lfloor qb \rfloor$ then set $q$ to the next higher integer
and compare $\lceil qa \rceil$ and $\lfloor qb \rfloor$ again.
Repeat until a value $q$ is found such that
$\lceil qa \rceil \leq \lfloor qb \rfloor.$
Since all smaller integers were tried as denominators and failed, 
the value $q$ found in this way is the smallest possible denominator of a
rational number in the interval $[a,b].$
As before, set $p = \lceil qa \rceil$ in order to obtain $a \leq \frac pq \leq b.$

This description glosses over some possible difficulties, such as how to evaluate
$\lceil qa \rceil$ (for example) if $a$ is irrational.
It would be nice to have a better algorithm, in particular one that wasn't
essentially "try every possible value until you find one that works."